# Grails Migrations Plugin Creating Triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, grails, liquibase

I have an SQL file with DML Trigger creations that I run as an SQL script. However, I'd like to include that in my Grails database migrations changelog. I run all of my other SQL scripts using the changelog (with the sqlFile tag). When I do this same process with my triggers sql file I get all sorts of invalid sql statement errors (invalid sql statement on "end;").

Is is having a problem because of the PL/SQL nature of triggers? If so, how can I get around this?

This is the type of statements I'm trying to run:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "A_HST"
     BEFORE
       delete or update
         on TableA
     for each row
       begin
          insert into A_history
            ( ID,
            VERSION,
            COMMENTS,
            description,
            NAME,
            UPDATEDBY_ID)
   values
     ( :old.id,
        :old.VERSION,
        :old.comments,
        :old.description,
        :old.name,
        :old.UPDATEDBY_ID);
    end;
```

/

ALTER TRIGGER "A_HST" ENABLE;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are having an issue with delimiters? Take a look at `endDelimiter` attribute in http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html

You could set the endDelimiter to ';;' and make sure that the CREATE TRIGGER statements are followed by ';;'

Comment: I'll look into the delimiter. I've noticed that dbm-update runs the sql files differently than running them through sqlplus or Toad/SQLDeveloper. Sometimes I'll get errors with sqlplus that I don't get with dbm-update... It's strange, but I'll try the delimiter idea and let you know if it works.

Comment: I've tried out this approach (setting endDelimiter to ';;' and replacing all single ';' to ';;'. The triggers do get put into the database. However, they have compilation errors because they are missing the ';' to end the statement...

Comment: This worked for me - I set endDelimiter="#" and used semicolons for line endings in my trigger script